# Difference between casting at the evaluation and casting afterwards

Tags: java, gwt

I just found a bug in a website I'm working on and I corrected it. My problem here is that even if I corrected it I don't understand what was the issue.

I have two dates (I can't use GregorianCalendar) and I want to evaluate the distance between these two in days. It's kind of trivial but my code had a weird behaviour.

For specific dates, for instance: 26/04/2008 and 26/05/2008 the number of days should be exactly 30 but I got -19. For other dates, it worked fine. Here is what I did:

```
    Date dMin = ... // -> 26/04/2008
    Date dMax = ... // -> 26/05/2008

    System.out.println((dMax.getTime()-dMin.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24)); // prints 30
    int i = (int) (dMax.getTime()-dMin.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24); // i = -19
```

So how did I correct it? I did something like this:

```
long i = (dMax.getTime()-dMin.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24);
```

And later on, just before I display it on screen, I would cast it as an integer and it's working fine.

I'm working with GWT and this calculus is done on the client side (so it's compiled as javascript).

Is there something I am missing there? I guess yes but I can't find out what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your cast (parentheses), see for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println((int)(1.2)*10); //prints 10
    System.out.println((int)(1.2*10)); //prints 12
}
```

So your `int i = (int) (dMax.getTime()-dMin.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24); // i = -19` first casts `dMax.getTime()-dMin.getTime()` to int before dividing - you possibly get an overflow there.

Answer (score 2):

`Date.getTime()` returns `long`. One month is (24*60*60*1000*30 =) 2,592,000,000 milliseconds. This value requires 32 bits, thus it doesn't fit into an unsigned integer (whose highest value is 2<sup>31</sup> -1). So when you cast `dMax.getTime()-dMin.getTime()` to `int` *before* dividing it with `1000*60*60*24`, there is a silent overflow error and the truncated result is interpreted as a negative `int` value.

After the division, the result is already small enough to fit into an `int`, so there is no overflow at the cast and the end result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

### Joda-Time

This kind of work is easier and more reliable if you utilize a good date-time library such as Joda-Time or JSR 310/Java 8.

### Example Code

Here’s some example code in Joda-Time 2.3 in Java 7.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

DateTime start = new DateTime(2008, 4, 26, 0, 0, 0, timeZone);
DateTime stop = new DateTime(2008, 5, 26, 0, 0, 0, timeZone);

int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween( start, stop ).getDays();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "start: " + start );
System.out.println( "stop: " + stop );
System.out.println( "daysBetween: " + daysBetween );
```

When executed…

```
start: 2008-04-26T00:00:00.000+02:00
stop: 2008-05-26T00:00:00.000+02:00
daysBetween: 30
```